# how do I set AWS Amplify environment variable from the command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-cli, aws-amplify-cli

I know how to do it from the console https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html

but I want to set the amplify environment variable from the command line. I couldn't find it here https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/amplify/index.html

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the solution was well hidden in https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/amplify/index.html

```
aws amplify update-branch --app-id $APPID --branch-name $DEPLOY_BRANCH --environment-variables REACT_APP_BUILD_NUMBER=$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
```

then in react

```
const version = parseInt(process.env.REACT_APP_BUILD_NUMBER as string);
```